# Financial crime involving reporting a higher price than paid, receiving reimbursement, and pocketing the difference

Tags: united-states, fraud

Here's a very simple example of the crime I'm describing:

A company has a policy of reimbursing salesmen for money spent on things intended to build relationships with potential clients: dinners, golf games, gifts, etcetera. To receive reimbursement, the salesman sends an invoice at the end of each month iterating each expense incurred during that month. However, the salesman inflates each expense by a small amount, 5-10%, and pockets the difference between the amount he is reimbursed and the amount he actually spent.

What is this called?

Comment: It's called fraud. Falsifying business expenses is indeed fraud. This is why the company should require receipts or provide a company card for the salepersons to use. Otherwise the reimbursements may not stand up to an audit as deductible business expenses, and could be converted to taxable income.

Comment: This is exactly what Enron have been doing but on a bigger scale and we al know how it ended.

Comment: @samll How are you able to comment on someone else's question without having at least 50 reputation points? This is strange.

Comment: @Flux - that was an answer that a moderator converted to a comment, that's how.

Answer (score 1):

> To receive reimbursement, the salesman sends an invoice at the end of
> each month iterating each expense incurred during that month. However,
> the salesman inflates each expense by a small amount, 5-10%, and
> pockets the difference between the amount he is reimbursed and the
> amount he actually spent.

What you are describing is theft.

A company can require that 100% of expenses be documented, but in reality there are some expenses that won't have a receipt. Currently the IRS only requires expenses above $75 to be connected to a receipt or other proof. But  a company can go beyond the IRS requirements, but if they meet the requirements the money isn't considered taxable income.

The issue for the company is not just the IRS requirement that the undocumented items should be considered as taxable income, there is also the issue of theft of company funds.

In places I have worked the list of allowable items that won't have a receipt is very small. Public transportation expenses is one item that can be reimbursed without a receipt, but then again the cost of each subway ride is only a couple of bucks.

One way to prevent some of the abuse is through the use of a company card, with the requirement that it be used exclusively for these expenses, and that all expenses be run through the card. That makes the real amount easier to get correct. There should still be a monthly requirement to connect every expense to a customer or potential customer.

Answer (score -3):

> However, the salesman inflates each expense by a small amount, 5-10%, and pockets the difference between the amount he is reimbursed and the amount he actually spent

This is meaningless.

Each expense would have to be accompanied by a **real receipt**.

Note that indeed the company ultimately needs that real paperwork to square their accounting and taxes.

Incredibly, the salesperson could be **generating fake receipts** (presumably using printers, etc).

That would be **falsifying documentation**.

As TTT explains, that is surely **fraud**.

If you want a more detailed investigation of the best legal terminology (in a given jurisdiction) ask on the excellent Law SE web site.

Again, what you ask is impossible - since expenses have to come with invoices.

Comment: This is not universally true.  I have worked with people from european institutions that have a set amount subsistence per day working away, and do not have to show receipts.   It seems to work exactly as described by the OP, in that this is supposed to be expensed as spent, but in reality is treated as "their" money and spent or pocketed as they wish.

Comment: Hi @Dave - Dave, that's totally, completely, different, that's called a per diem.  It has nothing whatsoever to do with expenses.  (I absolutely couldn't care less, but you're really mistaken to downvote; it may confuse anyone cruising here!)

Comment: @Dave - a per diem wouldn't apply here. It's just a regular acceptable business expense of a (legally capped) set amount, and it's up to the employee to be frugal and try to profit from it, or spend it.

Comment: @Fattie even though Dave was talking about something different, I agree with the first sentence that "this is not universally true". Consider cash purchases and tips, etc. So it's not "impossible". Other than that wording I agree with you.

Comment: Side note- I remember a story about Wells Fargo employees falsifying lunch receipts. They changed the time of the receipt to look like it was after hours because they were allowed to expense dinner if they worked late. Obviously it didn't go well for them.